# How to repair login screen without reinstalling gdm

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, gdm

I recently ran into an issue with my login screen switching to a default hi-contrast window management schema in Ubuntu, as opposed to the default dark colors. The problem (and a working, but not-as-versatile solution) is documented at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1324055.

How do I reconfigure my system to use the default settings when at the login screen, without reinstalling gdm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue pretty easily; I enabled assistive technologies from the System > Preferences > Assistive Technologies dialog, then logged out, opened the Assistive dialog, checked the checkbox for the high-contrast view, unchecked the checkbox, and closed the dialog.  That changed the user list coloration, and didn't restore the default theme.

This appears to be [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdm/+bug/402017).  They call it `ACODBIT` -- the [Accessibility Checkbox Of Death By Inappropriate Theme](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdm/+bug/402017/comments/8).

What's happening is that checking the accessibility option changes a GDM configuration file when checked, and when unchecked the file isn't properly restored.

The file is ***/var/lib/gdm/.gconf.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml***; all you need to do to fix the problem state is restore the original file.  There are several ways to do this; which ones are easier than reinstalling ... is debatable.  An incomplete list:

- Copy the file from another system that doesn't exhibit the problem.  This could be another computer running Ubuntu 9.10, or a 9.10 LiveCD.
- Mount a LiveCD's *casper/filesystem.squashfs* file and access the file from there:

  1. insert your LiveCD and allow Gnome to automount it;
  2. in a terminal window, run this to mount the LiveCD's filesystem 
     (replace */media/cdrom0* with the location your LiveCD was mounted to):

     ```
     sudo mount /media/cdrom0/casper/filesystem.squashfs /mnt -o loop
     ```
  3. copy the file from LiveCD filesystem:

     ```
     sudo cp /mnt/var/lib/gdm/.gconf.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml /var/lib/gdm/.gconf.defaults/
     ```
- Restore it from a backup, if you have one.
- Reinstall the *gdm* package.  For beginners, this really is the easiest option.  If the package is still available in your system's package cache (*/var/cache/apt/archives*), reinstalling *will not re-download the package*.  You can use one of these to reinstall:

  - Synaptic Package Manager, on the System > Administration menu; or
  - Aptitude on the commandline, with the command

    ```
    sudo aptitude reinstall gdm
    ```

Comment: my question is, now that i've *enabled* the "Assistive Technologies" in order to test this bug, *how the hell do i make it go away*??  dammit, ubuntu... this is why i'm never again installing you on my own bare-metal machines.

Comment: ok, apparently you *disable* "Assistive Technologies" by going into System > Preferences > Keyboard, select the *"Accessibility"* tab, and uncheck *"Accessibility features can be toggled with keyboard shortcuts"* ...  _*grumbles*_